# Java runtime environment installation on W10 64 bit

Tags: java

Cannot work with Base document because after installing several Java e.g. jre-9.04, a message appears : the folder you selected does not contain Java runtime environment. Have a 64 bit W10 laptop

Comment: I'm confused, are you trying to fix this in Windows, or the WIndows Subsystem for Linux (which is "Ubuntu on Windows" as some peopel call it)?

Answer (score -1):

Normally in other OS jdk fits the job with out jre.. you may wanna run this being root or using sudo like below. Remember to check the software version which it allows to be runned on, and the program your using is it local?
But run this.

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Then

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Now ...

```
sudo apt-get install default-jdk
```

Then Again

```
sudo apt-get install default-jre
```

Finally

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: 1) OP doesn't state whether this is about plain Windows or WSL. 2) I doubt that the JRE for Ubuntu runs as expected on WSL. -1